# Google Chrome Drop Down Menus not Working

Tags: google-chrome

I just recently noticed that some drop down menus on Google Chrome act funny whenever I try to use them.

(Seriously, I need reputation points to post an image? That has got the be the dumbest thing I've ever seen for a help forum. I have show what's going on. Now I need to link off-site...)

[image: Pic Here]

They do that and if the menu is long enough to scroll, scrolling tends to jumble the words around much like the highlighted bar that you see in the pic.

I tried going to the Google forums first, but they don't seem to know what's happening, so I'm wondering if the problem may be related to Ubuntu/Linux somehow. Whenever I start Chrome via the terminal, it starts, but all of this appears for me:

```
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
[9:24:0112/205123:ERROR:webgraphicscontext3d_command_buffer_impl.cc(279)] Context dead on arrival. Last error: 5
[22388:22388:0112/205123:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(153)] Could not send GpuCommandBufferMsg_Initialize.
[22388:22388:0112/205123:ERROR:webgraphicscontext3d_command_buffer_impl.cc(200)] CommandBufferProxy::Initialize failed.
[22388:22388:0112/205123:ERROR:webgraphicscontext3d_command_buffer_impl.cc(217)] Failed to initialize command buffer.
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
[22388:22388:0112/205124:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(153)] Could not send GpuCommandBufferMsg_Initialize.
[22388:22388:0112/205124:ERROR:webgraphicscontext3d_command_buffer_impl.cc(200)] CommandBufferProxy::Initialize failed.
[22388:22388:0112/205124:ERROR:webgraphicscontext3d_command_buffer_impl.cc(217)] Failed to initialize command buffer.
[9:24:0112/205124:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(153)] Could not send GpuCommandBufferMsg_Initialize.
[9:24:0112/205124:ERROR:webgraphicscontext3d_command_buffer_impl.cc(200)] CommandBufferProxy::Initialize failed.
[9:24:0112/205124:ERROR:webgraphicscontext3d_command_buffer_impl.cc(217)] Failed to initialize command buffer.
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
[22388:22388:0112/205124:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(153)] Could not send GpuCommandBufferMsg_Initialize.
[22388:22388:0112/205124:ERROR:webgraphicscontext3d_command_buffer_impl.cc(200)] CommandBufferProxy::Initialize failed.
[22388:22388:0112/205124:ERROR:webgraphicscontext3d_command_buffer_impl.cc(217)] Failed to initialize command buffer.
[22388:22473:0112/205124:ERROR:get_updates_processor.cc(240)] PostClientToServerMessage() failed during GetUpdates
[22388:22388:0112/205125:ERROR:extension_downloader.cc(699)] Invalid URL: '' for extension pbnmelddedlommnmllmfhoephaidddmk
```

It also does this after a little while:

```
[22388:22388:0112/210337:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(209)] Gdk: gdk_window_set_user_time called on non-toplevel
```

And it just keep bringing that same message up again and again and doesn't seem to stop. Any help on what's going on and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Uninstall Chrome completely.

After you have done so, goto the Ubuntu Software Center and search "Chromium".

Chromium is an open source version of Chrome and it is pretty much the same thing.

I know this does not solve your problem, but it is easier than fixing the issue.

Comment: It seems you know what's going on then. If you could, could you let me know how to actually fix it? I also use a Chromebook sometimes and Bookmarks to not sync between Chrome and Chromium, so I would rather fix chrome.

Comment: Why would using Chromium help? The code for menus and things are exactly the same. Do you know what's going on and why? Please explain and post any links to bug reports if it is a known bug.

Comment: Im not sure why the bug occurs to be honest. I used Ubuntu on a Chromebook and I ended up using Chromium to get rid of the bug. It's the same anyways, so it doesn't matter really.